# make list separate values

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
[[[116 114]
 [111 104]]
```

Is there a way to make this:

```
[[[116,114]
  [111,104]]
```

or a command to make the sum of this look like this:

```
[[[230]
 [214]]
```

If I use `np.sum()`, it returns `444`.

Comment: What are you asking?  How to change the displayed representation or how to perform a sum along an axis or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array `tolist` function:

```
>>> r = numpy.array([[116, 114],[111, 104]])
>>> [sum(e) for e in r.tolist()]
[230, 215]
```

Answer (score 3):

Specify `axis`:

```
>>> a = np.array([[[116,114], [111,104]]])

>>> np.sum(a, axis=-1)
array([[230, 215]])

>>> a.sum(axis=-1)
array([[230, 215]])
```